# Windows 10 always at 80-90% memory usage

Tags: windows, windows-10, memory, memory-leaks

My PC have been running slow for a few weeks now, and I've never really had any time to check why, I've always assumed my PC was just getting old.

I recently checked my task manager, and saw that even if I wasn't doing anything my memory usage was either on 80%-90%, it never goes lower than that. Even after a reboot.

I've always used my PC for non-pc heavy gaming when I have time, movie streaming on netflix, listening to music and etc. So I've never really encountered any problems in the last 4 years of using my pc.

[image: Image of task manager here]

I'd like some insight on what can be done to fix this issue, I've been told it might be a malware issue, I went and got MalwareBytes for that then quarantined and deleted the threats found, but the issue is still here.

Comment: Nothing looks off from your photo. Can you use the resource monitor (press win+r and type in resmon.exe), filter by private ram (click the private column). Take a screenshot of that page. It tends to provide more info (task manager tends to hide certain system features) Also list how much memory your computer has.

Comment: @user173724 https://i.imgur.com/4rb1fpc.png right now it's at 30-35% usage, on active use. That's what bothers me, sometimes, it just shoots up to 80% even when I'm not doing anything. I find it suspicious because I doubt normal programs would eat up the whole 5gb available

Comment: You are only using 33% here. I have no clue what is going on here. Next time you see 80%, add another photo, but for the time being, it look ok.

Comment: Post a screenshot of Task Manager - Performance tab showing memory information when the problem occurs. That is usually the best place to start with memory problems. Very often the problem is not due to a process at all.

Answer (score 0):

The screenshot of Task Manager is helpful. It shows <1 GB of RAM in use, which implies your PC has only ~1 GB available. No obvious malware is listed, though.
1 GB is marginal for most Windows setups (anything after XP), so if feasible, I'd add RAM.

If that's *not* feasible, look to the applications consuming most RAM, e.g. Chrome. There are at least 7 Chrome processes consuming about half the RAM. To shed some of this usage, *close* all tabs, close Chrome and then reopen only one tab at a time. Also, get rid of any extensions that might consume RAM -- experiment.

While it's possible to increase effective RAM by increasing Virtual Memory, this is drastically slower than actual RAM.

Comment: Like i've commented above: i.imgur.com/4rb1fpc.png right now it's at 30-35% usage, on active use. That's what bothers me, sometimes, it just shoots up to 80% even when I'm not doing anything. I find it suspicious because I doubt normal programs would eat up the whole 5gb available

Comment: @JoshQ, Then something is *very* odd: you claim 5 GB available, but add up all the processes you show running and it's <1 GB! Try running SysInternals Process Explorer as Administrator and see if there are hidden processes not showing in Task Manager.